# Is making AJAX site crawlable AND degrading gracefully with JS turned off possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, progressive-enhancement, graceful-degradation

According to [this spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started), making AJAX site crawlable by Googlebot means that you have to use hashbang (#!) links in it which means it won't degrade gracefully when JS is turned off (or progressively enhance when it is turned on). This might mean that crawlability and graceful degradation/progressive enhancement are mutually exclusive in this case. Is it in fact so? Is there something that can be done about that?

*Note: To be transparent I'll note that this question was also [asked](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35400/is-making-ajax-site-crawlable-and-degrading-gracefully-with-js-turned-off-possib) in Pro Webmasters site but I consider it interesting also from a purely programmatic point of view.*

Answer (score 4):

When possible, I like to only use AJAX to load new pages when `history.pushState` is available. When `history.pushState` is not available, I fall back to non-AJAX. While this may be a sub-par experience for those without `history.pushState`, it makes sure the URL is always pointing to the right place and that the site will be accessible to both Google and users with JavaScript disabled.